# Find all subjects that match X but don't match Y

Tags: sparql

I have a simple "Registrations" table that contain students registered for courses. A student can be registered for multiple courses.

I want to **find all students registered for course 1234 that were not registered for course 5678**.

So I tried this attempt:

```
SELECT ?student_id
WHERE {
    ?registration :R-Student_id ?student_id ;
                  :R-Course_code ?course_code .
    FILTER(?course_code = "1234") .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?registration :R-Course_code "5678" .
    }
}
ORDER BY ?student_id
```

But it seems like the last `FILTER NOT EXISTS` makes no difference to the query? I can still find student_ids from the query result that are also registered for the second course :/

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve it using some sort of "self join":

```
SELECT ?student_id
WHERE {
    ?r1 :R-Student_id ?student_id ;
        :R-Course_code "1234" .

    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?r2 :R-Student_id ?student_id ;
            :R-Course_code "5678" .
    }
}
ORDER BY ?student_id
```